# How to move an already moved file to new directory

Tags: java, file, java-io

I am trying to move a single File between folders. I use file.renameTo() to move my file.

```
//moving the file to new folder
//this is success 
boolean fileMoveCompleted = finalFileToProcess
                        .renameTo(new File(processingFolderName
                                + File.separator + finalFileToProcess.getName()));

//now trying to move the renamed file to another folder
//this is failing
 fileMoveCompleted = finalFileToProcess
                                .renameTo(new File(successFolderName
                                        + File.separator
                                        + finalFileToProcess.getName()));
```

After the first `renameTo` the file path still points to the older path. Is there any way I can move the same file to another directory ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to keep the first target file of renameTo as reference and rename that one.

```
File processing = new File(processingFolderName 
                        + File.separator 
                        + finalFileToProcess.getName());
boolean fileMoveCompleted = finalFileToProcess.renameTo(processing);
File finished = new File(successFolderName 
                        + File.separator 
                        + finalFileToProcess.getName());
fileMoveCompleted = processing.renameTo(finished);
```

But as [File.renameTo's JavaDoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#renameTo(java.io.File)) suggests, you should better use [Files.move](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#move(java.nio.file.Path,%20java.nio.file.Path,%20java.nio.file.CopyOption...)).